# Gradient definition

Tags: vector-analysis

I saw recently the follow gradient definition

$$\nabla\phi = \lim_{\Delta\text{Vol}\to0}\frac{1}{\Delta\text{Vol}} \int_{\partial\text{Vol}}\phi\  \text{d}\vec{A}$$

I can't get that definition using $\lim$ and $\int_{\partial\text{Vol}}$ to get a differential operator. $\phi$ is a scalar function.

Can someone help me to understand? Regards!

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @scoopfaze, I didn't understand the lim and integral to get the gradient, a differential vector operator. Can you explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: I was actually making a point about clarifying your question. Very open-ended questions tend to attract downvotes, so I was trying to help you prevent that.

Comment: @scoopfaze, thank you for the advice. I edited the question.

Comment: No worries. Cheers!

Comment: Do you know the Divergence Theorem?

Comment: @TedShifrin, yeah, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so to fix ideas I'll do this in $3$-space, but it works in any dimension.

Fix $\mathbf a$ and let $B(\mathbf a,r)$ be a ball of radius $r$ centered at $\mathbf a$. (You can use other shapes, too, if you so desire, but they do have to shrink down to the point $\bf a$ in a reasonable manner.) Let's consider the first coordinate of your equation. To get $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}(\mathbf a)$ I want to take the first coordinate of the right-hand side, so I consider
$$\iint_{\partial B(\mathbf a,r)} (\phi\vec i)\cdot d\vec A.$$
(So we're going to consider the flux of the vector field $\vec F = \phi\vec i$ across the surface. The divergence of $\vec F$ is $\partial\phi/\partial x$.)
By the Divergence Theorem, this integral is equal to
$$\iiint_{B(\mathbf a,r)} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\,dV \approx \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}(\mathbf a)\text{vol}(B(\mathbf a,r)),$$
by continuity. Thus, to get the correct statement in what you posted, you need to take the limit of the integral *divided by* the volume of the region. (Obviously, if you do not do that, the RHS just goes to $0$.) That is, the correct statement is
$$\nabla\phi(\mathbf a) = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac 1{\text{vol}(B(\mathbf a,r))}\iint_{\partial B(\mathbf a,r)} \phi\,d\vec A.$$

Comment: That's precisely the Divergence Theorem: $\iint_{\partial R}\vec F\cdot d\vec A = \iiint_R \text{div}(\vec F)\,dV$.

Comment: Even it being $\phi$ a scalar function, can I use the Divergence Theorem? As you put it, $\vec{F}$ is a function. Another doubt, did you use the $\lim$ because you approximated $dV$ by $\text{vol}(B(a,r))$ in the 2nd equation? Thank you for the answer, @TedShifrin.

Comment: Yes, the approximation is only an equality in the limit (and this requires continuity). I edited to make things a bit clearer in the text.

Comment: I was writing down and noticed that I would get a scalar value for the gradient because using $\phi\vec{i}\ . \ d\vec{A}$ I get a scalar, am I right? And thinking that scalar up the tensor rank, I’m confused. Thank you!

Comment: I changed my question. You were right regarding that should be $\frac{1}{\text{Vol}}$ before the $\int$, but yet I can't understand you answer because I'm getting a scalar value instead vector, as should be due the fact I'm dealing with a gradient. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remember that I computed the first coordinate of both sides of the equation (by dotting with $\vec i$ on the right-hand side). You do this with $\vec j$ and $\vec k$ and you get the entire expression for $\nabla\phi$.

Comment: Yes, I remember. Let's consider a cube. In the plane y-z we have $d\vec{A}$ as $\vec{i}dydz$, right? Evaluating the integrand in the 1st equation, I'll get a scalar ($\phi\vec{i}.\vec{i}dydz$). I can do this in all over directions. Then, when I apply the Divergente Theorem, I'll get a scalar not a vector as should be. This is getting me confuse. Could you please clarify to me. Thank you, Ted. You're helping a lot!

Comment: Yes, so the $\vec i$ component gives you approximately $\big(\phi(a_1+\Delta x/2,a_2,a_3)-\phi(a_1-\Delta x/2,a_2,a_3)\big)\Delta y\Delta z \approx \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}(\mathbf a)\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z$. Dividing by the volume gives $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}(\mathbf a)$, as it should. We're not supposed to get a vector. I remind you (again) that we're finding the first coordinate of the vector.

Comment: Yes, we're finding the first coordinate of the vector. But it shouldn't have the $\vec{i}$ following it to show that indeed is a vector in that direction?

Comment: No. We dotted with $\vec i$ at the outset to get just the scalar.

Comment: Solving the integrand in the $x$-direction $$[\phi(x+\Delta x)-\phi(x)]\Delta y\Delta z\ \vec{i}$$
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\ \vec{i}$$
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\Delta\text{Vol}\ \vec{i}$$ This way I can get the $\vec{i}$. I can solve it, but I remain don't understanding the formulation. I saw that works, I'll get a vector in all directions. Apparently using the Divergent Theorem I can't get the same result.

Comment: The Divergence theorem gives the flux of a vector field across a closed surface. Flux is a scalar quantity. I do not know what your problem is. If you know the components $(a,b,c)$ of a vector $a\vec i+b\vec j+c\vec k$, then you surely know the vector.

Comment: I have a scalar function $\phi(x,y,z)$ and I looking for the gradient of this function, that it will be a vector. According the definition I saw, I can compute the divergent using $\nabla\phi = \lim_{\Delta\text{Vol}\to0}\frac{1}{\Delta\text{Vol}} \int_{\partial\text{Vol}}\phi\  \text{d}\vec{A}$. Solving for the $x$ direction I get $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\vec{i}$. I'm trying to understand from where comes that definition because it really works. But trying the Divergence Theorem, as you said, I can't get the same result. Now did you understand me?

Comment: No, you're being too stubborn. If I have two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$, and I check that $\vec A\cdot\vec i = \vec B\cdot\vec i$ and the same for $\vec j$ and $\vec k$, then it is immediate that $\vec A=\vec B$. I quit.

Comment: Ted, I didn't read properly your last comments, I'm sorry. Now I understood perfectly. Thank you so much. Regards!